# ReadAll not declared by package iocompiler - Golang

Tags: go

I am using golang in my project.

The code is as follows

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"

)

....
if response.StatusCode != 200 {
        respBdy, _ := io.ReadAll(response.Body)
        return fmt.Errorf("%v response from client: %v", response.StatusCode, respBdy)
    }
```

When i run the project using `make run`, i am getting the following error

`go-tools@v0.0.0-20220528203058-9108e3643722/messengers/client.go:133:17: undefined: io.ReadAll`

On debugging, i can understand the problem is `ReadAll not declared by package iocompiler`

Any idea on how to fix this?

Edit: The go version i am using is

```
go version
go version go1.15.6 darwin/amd64
```

Comment: also, add a version of the go in which you are working

Comment: Change `io.ReadAll` to `ioutil.ReadAll`. In import `io` to `io/ioutil`.

Comment: @avinash other developers are using the same codebase and it is working for them

Comment: @ManjeetThakur: The version i am using is go 1.13

Comment: `io.ReadAll` is only available ^1.16 so use so you can use `ioutil.ReadAll`

Comment: @ManjeetThakur when i use go version it is showing as `go1.15.6 darwin/amd64`. But in go.mod file it is shown as `go 1.13`. Also how is this working for t=others. They also have the same code right. I am a beginner in this language

Comment: "The version i am using is go 1.13" So you found the problem. Use 1.18.

Comment: @Volker when i use go version it is showing as go1.15.6 darwin/amd64. But in go.mod file it is shown as go 1.13

Comment: Use Go 1.18. And update your go.mod it seems outdated.

Comment: Context: `ReadAll` was part of package `io/ioutil`, but starting with Go 1.16 (as [documented](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReadAll)), it was duplicated (but not moved, for backwards compatibility) to `io`. As for the `go` directive in `go.mod`: as described [here](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-go), this is the _assumed_ version - but regardless, your local Go version will be used for compilation (which explains why it may work for others, but not you). So, as suggested, upgrade your go directive to >=1.16 in `go.mod` and upgrade locally (or, as a workaround, roll with `io/ioutil` instead)

Comment: (Reason I'm calling reverting back to `io/ioutil` a workaround is the `As of Go 1.16, the same functionality is now provided by package io or package os, and those implementations should be preferred in new code.` line in the `io/ioutil` [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Manjeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4303758/manjeet-thakur) and [Emile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3521243/emile-pels) stated, starting from `go1.16`'s release, the functions from [io/ioutil](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil) are moved to [io](https://pkg.go.dev/io) package.

```
Discard => io.Discard
NopCloser => io.NopCloser
ReadAll => io.ReadAll
ReadDir => os.ReadDir
ReadFile => os.ReadFile
TempDir => os.MkdirTemp
TempFile => os.CreateTemp
WriteFile => os.WriteFile
```

Linking [release notes](https://go.dev/doc/go1.16#ioutil) of `go1.16` for reference.

About the mismatch of go versions: `go1.13` in `go.mod` and `go1.15` in terminal, the go version in `go.mod` gets added depending on the version when it was initialised using `go mod init [module-path]`. GoDoc page for [go mod init](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-init) doesn't clear your doubt but attaching for ref.

In other words, the `go.mod` doesn't denote your local go version. Rather, it gives the minimal go version and imported package's versions that will let your project (as module) run hassle-free.

I found a sample from an old project. Will try to explain on it.

```
module project-name

go 1.14

require (
    github.com/go-redis/redis/v7 v7.4.0
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.6.1
    github.com/vektra/mockery v1.1.2 // indirect
)
```

This means the project requires `go1.14`, along with `redis@v7.4.0`, `testify@v1.6.1` and `mockery@v1.1.2` at the very least. Lower than these versions "might" still work. Not recommended. Higher than those versions are expected to be better, but there is a possibility of change of names or package name like above. More details at [gomod-ref](https://go.dev/doc/modules/gomod-ref).

Just another bit of info: the `io` and `io/util` are part of Go's [standard library](https://pkg.go.dev/std). This means that in order to use the function as `io.ReadAll`, you would need higher version of standard library, and so, higher version of Go (`1.16` at least).

> **Conclusion:** You can still keep `go1.13` in `go.mod`. Just upgrade the go version in local. And if other devs are kind enough to let you upgrade in `go.mod` too, do it!

**Opinion:** I personally recommend `go1.17`'s latest for now until all external packages implement `go1.18` and `generics`.